# Is it possible to append the currency sign in YUI2 datatable after the numerals?

Tags: alfresco-share, yui-datatable, yui2

I would like to position the currency label after the numerals in the datatable. I currently have this configuration:

```
currencyOptions: { prefix: '€', decimalPlaces: 2, decimalSeparator: ',', thousandsSeparator: '.'}
```

but this prefixes the sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `suffix` option instead of `prefix`